# How to catch a rejected promises in same time order as resolves?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

Promises which resolve() or reject() can be handled in order with `.then()` regardless if they are resolved or rejected:

```
const getRecordById = (id) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1;
        if (randNum === 1) {
            resolve({ id, firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe' });
        } else {
            reject(`user id ${id} not found`);
        }
    });
};

for (let id = 1; id <= 10; id++) {
    getRecordById(id)
        .then(
            (record) => { console.log(`you got record #${record.id}`); },
            (errMessage) => { console.log(`error was: ${errMessage}`); }
        );
}
```

[image]

But I read in [articles like this one](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/fundamentals/promise-reject) that e.g.

> many libraries and frameworks assume that promises are always rejected with an error

and so one should instead reject with an error like this: `reject(new Error('Oops!'));` instead of rejecting with a string.

But when I reject with an Error object, why do all the rejections complete after the resolves?

```
const getRecordById = (id) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1;
        if (randNum === 1) {
            resolve({ id, firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe' }); 
        } else {
            reject (new Error(`user id ${id} not found`)); 
        }
    });
};

for (let id = 1; id <= 10; id++) {
    getRecordById(id)
        .then((record) => { console.log(`you got record #${record.id}`); })
        .catch((errMessage) => { console.log(`error was: ${errMessage}`); });
}
```

[image]

Comment: I found article that [explains](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/the-real-difference-between-catch-vs-onrejected-15cab8978e92/) difference between `.catch` and `onRejected` callbacks. It's about how runtime queues tasks, if I understand it correctly.

Comment: I think you want https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled

Comment: The type of the returned "cause" as nothing to do with that behavior, in both case you are not handling the rejection the same way, one handles it directly from the initial Promise while the other one handles the error from the Promise returned by `.then()`. That's at least one microtask later.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24662289/when-is-thensuccess-fail-considered-an-antipattern-for-promises (Though I'm not sure how well it explains the timing issue, but I don't have time to dig a better dupe target, so won't hammer this for now)

Comment: You still can use `.then(…, …)` instead of `.then(…).catch(…)` when you reject with an error not with a string.

Comment: I think [capchuck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16752963/capchuck) is right here is some more details about [fullfilled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Comment: You changed _two things_, you're asking about the one that _didn't_ cause the different behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

In the second example the errors are shown at the bottom is not because reject was an error object. In the first code you have handled error inside `.then` but in the second code snippet there is `.catch` for handling exception. Second code will log in same order as first if you handle error inside `.then`.

```js
const getRecordById = (id) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1;
        if (randNum === 1) {
            resolve({ id, firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe' }); 
        } else {
            reject (new Error(`user id ${id} not found`)); 
        }
    });
};

for (let id = 1; id <= 10; id++) {
    getRecordById(id)
        .then((record) => { console.log(`you got record #${record.id}`)},
            (errMessage) => { console.log(`error was: ${errMessage}`); })
}
```